# Query for values in nested maps

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In my data structure I have nested attributes/maps.
E.g.

```
{
  nodes:
    apple:
      tags: [a,b]
    orange:
      tags: [b,c]
 }
```

My goal is to have a query that returns all nodes that have a tag of `b` for example.
I'm using the golang aws sdk to query DynamoDB.

```
filter := expression.Name("nodes.*.tags").Contains(status))
```

This does not work because the `*` does not seem to work as a wildcard here it seems. I also tried `?` but same.

What however does work is: `filter := expression.Name("nodes.apple.tags").Contains(status))` for example.
But this way I have to name all the nodes in the query.

Is there a way I can make my query work with some kind of wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

No, your second example is the only way to achieve it. As you store it all on a single item, you could probably have a top level attributes which is a list containing all possible tags in the item. You can then use a FilterExpression to see if it contains a given value then work out which nodes you want on the client side.

Comment: I was afraid of that yea. Putting things at the top-level would solve it but then I have overhead somewhere else. Thanks!